# Handling screen resolution changes for QML Animations

Tags: javascript, qml

I am a creating a fully scalable application on QML, what I need to know is how do I handle screen changes, for example this elements animation works for 1920x1080:

```
EventLog{
        id: eventlog
        x: 0
        y: 1000
        z: 10
        NumberAnimation{id: showeventPanel; target: eventlog; properties: "y"; to: 710; duration: 500}
    }
```

But I cannot anchor this element otherwise the animation will not take place, so for other resolutions this element will not be correctly placed, I realise that I can set the the anchor to anchors: undefined but how can I accurately set the x and y to move too the correct position on the screen?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What exactly did you want to archive? Is your element a child of `Window`? In this case you can bind your animation or whatever to `Window.onWidth[Height]Changed` to track size changing

Comment: Yes the element is a child of window, what I want to achieve is to consistently centre my element and still have the animation run to the correct x or y position, say if I want my element to go to centre of the window, how would I bind that for different resolutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found, though not elegant, works to a certain degree. I anchored the element as so and set it to a dummy rect(centreRect) that I anchored to the correct x and y position:

```
CameraControlPanel{
        id: control_Panel
//        x: 1916
//        y: 270
        anchors {
            verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            right: parent.right

        }
        anchors.rightMargin: -635

        NumberAnimation{id: showPanel; target: control_Panel; properties: "x"; to: centreRect.x; duration: 500}
        z: 10
    }
```

Then when I needed to start the 'showPanel' animation I set the the anchors to undefined as so:

```
        control_Panel.anchors.verticalCenter = undefined
        control_Panel.anchors.right = undefined
```

When I needed to return the element to the correct position, I reset the anchors that were there previously.